# repositioning a menu on shopify debut theme using css / html

Tags: html, css, shopify

I have a website which is is built using shopify which is using the debut theme.

In my header I have positioned my logo in the centre of the page which has pushed my main menu down beneath the logo, and i want to position it on the left of the logo. Whilst aligning with the icons on the right of the logo.

I can post my theme.css code but its quite large.

This is the section of code that i believe i need to target.

```
<nav class="small--hide border-bottom" id="AccessibleNav" role="navigation">
    <ul class="site-nav list--inline site-nav--centered" id="SiteNav">
        <li class="site-nav--active">
            <a href="/" class="site-nav__link site-nav__link--main site-nav__link--active" aria-current="page"><span class="site-nav__label">Home</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/pages/about" class="site-nav__link site-nav__link--main"><span class="site-nav__label">About</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/products/remedi-propolis-gin" class="site-nav__link site-nav__link--main"><span class="site-nav__label">Shop</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/pages/contact" class="site-nav__link site-nav__link--main"><span class="site-nav__label">Contact</span></a>
        </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

The header.liquid file which relates to the header tag is as follows

```
  <header class="site-header{% if section.settings.align_logo == 'left' %} border-bottom logo--left{% else %} logo--center{% endif %}" role="banner">
<div class="grid grid--no-gutters grid--table site-header__mobile-nav">
  {% if section.settings.align_logo == 'center' %}
    {%- assign logo_classes = 'medium-up--one-third medium-up--push-one-third logo-align--center' -%}
  {% else %}
    {%- assign logo_classes = 'medium-up--one-quarter logo-align--left' -%}
  {% endif %}

  <div class="grid__item {{ logo_classes }}">
    {% comment %}
      Use the uploaded logo from theme settings if enabled.
      Site name gets precedence with H1 tag on homepage, div on other pages.
    {% endcomment %}
    {% if request.page_type == 'index' %}
      <h1 class="h2 site-header__logo">
    {% else %}
      <div class="h2 site-header__logo">
    {% endif %}
      {% if section.settings.logo %}
        {%- assign img_url = section.settings.logo | img_url: '1x1' | replace: '_1x1.', '_{width}x.' -%}
        <a href="{{ routes.root_url }}" class="site-header__logo-image{% if section.settings.align_logo == 'center' %} site-header__logo-image--centered{% endif %}" data-image-loading-animation>
          {% capture logo_alt %}{{ section.settings.logo.alt | default: shop.name }}{% endcapture %}
          <img class="lazyload js"
               src="{{ section.settings.logo | img_url: '300x300' }}"
               data-src="{{ img_url }}"
               data-widths="[180, 360, 540, 720, 900, 1080, 1296, 1512, 1728, 2048]"
               data-aspectratio="{{ section.settings.logo.aspect_ratio }}"
               data-sizes="auto"
               alt="{{ logo_alt | escape }}"
               style="max-width: {{ section.settings.logo_max_width }}px">
          <noscript>
            {% capture image_size %}{{ section.settings.logo_max_width | escape }}x{% endcapture %}
            <img src="{{ section.settings.logo | img_url: image_size }}"
                 srcset="{{ section.settings.logo | img_url: image_size }} 1x, {{ section.settings.logo | img_url: image_size, scale: 2 }} 2x"
                 alt="{{ section.settings.logo.alt | default: shop.name }}"
                 style="max-width: {{ section.settings.logo_max_width }}px;">
          </noscript>
        </a>
      {% else %}
        <a class="site-header__logo-link" href="{{ routes.root_url }}">{{ shop.name }}</a>
      {% endif %}
    {% if request.page_type == 'index' %}
      </h1>
    {% else %}
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>

  {% if section.settings.align_logo == 'left' %}
    <nav class="grid__item medium-up--one-half small--hide" id="AccessibleNav" role="navigation">
      {% include 'site-nav', linklist: section.settings.main_linklist %}
    </nav>
  {% endif %}

  <div class="grid__item {% if section.settings.align_logo == 'left' %}medium-up--one-quarter{% else %}medium-up--one-third medium-up--push-one-third{% endif %} text-right site-header__icons{% if shop.customer_accounts_enabled %} site-header__icons--plus{% endif %}">
    <div class="site-header__icons-wrapper">

      <button type="button" class="btn--link site-header__icon site-header__search-toggle js-drawer-open-top" data-predictive-search-open-drawer>
        {% include 'icon-search' %}
        <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'layout.navigation.search' | t }}</span>
      </button>

      {% if shop.customer_accounts_enabled %}
        {% if customer %}
          <a href="{{ routes.account_url }}" class="site-header__icon site-header__account">
            {% include 'icon-login' %}
            <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'layout.customer.account' | t }}</span>
          </a>
        {% else %}
          <a href="{{ routes.account_login_url }}" class="site-header__icon site-header__account">
            {% include 'icon-login' %}
            <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'layout.customer.log_in' | t }}</span>
          </a>
        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}

      <a href="{{ routes.cart_url }}" class="site-header__icon site-header__cart">
        {% include 'icon-cart' %}
        <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'layout.cart.title' | t }}</span>
        <div id="CartCount" class="site-header__cart-count{% if cart.item_count == 0 %} hide{% endif %} critical-hidden" data-cart-count-bubble>
          <span data-cart-count>{{ cart.item_count }}</span>
          <span class="icon__fallback-text medium-up--hide">{{ 'layout.cart.items_count' | t: count: cart.item_count }}</span>
        </div>
      </a>

      {% unless linklists[section.settings.main_linklist] == blank %}
        <button type="button" class="btn--link site-header__icon site-header__menu js-mobile-nav-toggle mobile-nav--open" aria-controls="MobileNav"  aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ 'layout.navigation.menu' | t }}">
          {% include 'icon-hamburger' %}
          {% include 'icon-close' %}
        </button>
      {% endunless %}
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<nav class="mobile-nav-wrapper medium-up--hide critical-hidden" role="navigation">
  <ul id="MobileNav" class="mobile-nav">
    {% for link in linklists[section.settings.main_linklist].links %}
      {%- assign outerLoopIndex = forloop.index -%}

      <li class="mobile-nav__item{% unless forloop.last %} border-bottom{% endunless %}">
        {% if link.links != blank %}
          {% capture child_list_handle %}{{ link.handle }}-{{ outerLoopIndex }}{% endcapture %}
          <button type="button" class="btn--link js-toggle-submenu mobile-nav__link{% if link.child_active %} mobile-nav__link--active{% endif %}" data-target="{{ child_list_handle }}" data-level="1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="mobile-nav__label">{{ link.title | escape }}</span>
            <div class="mobile-nav__icon">
              {% include 'icon-chevron-right' %}
            </div>
          </button>
          <ul class="mobile-nav__dropdown" data-parent="{{ child_list_handle }}" data-level="2">
            <li class="visually-hidden" tabindex="-1" data-menu-title="2">
              {{- link.title }} {{ 'layout.navigation.menu' | t -}}
            </li>
            <li class="mobile-nav__item border-bottom">
              <div class="mobile-nav__table">
                <div class="mobile-nav__table-cell mobile-nav__return">
                  <button class="btn--link js-toggle-submenu mobile-nav__return-btn" type="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="{{ link.title }}">
                    {% include 'icon-chevron-left' %}
                  </button>
                </div>
                <span class="mobile-nav__sublist-link mobile-nav__sublist-header mobile-nav__sublist-header--main-nav-parent">
                  <span class="mobile-nav__label">{{ link.title | escape }}</span>
                </span>
              </div>
            </li>

            {% for childlink in link.links %}
              <li class="mobile-nav__item{% unless forloop.last %} border-bottom{% endunless %}">
                {% if childlink.links != blank %}
                  {% capture grandchild_list_handle %}{{ childlink.handle }}-{{ outerLoopIndex }}-{{ forloop.index }}{% endcapture %}
                  <button type="button" class="btn--link js-toggle-submenu mobile-nav__link mobile-nav__sublist-link" data-target="{{ grandchild_list_handle }}" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="mobile-nav__label">{{ childlink.title | escape }}</span>
                    <div class="mobile-nav__icon">
                      {% include 'icon-chevron-right' %}
                    </div>
                  </button>
                  <ul class="mobile-nav__dropdown" data-parent="{{ grandchild_list_handle }}" data-level="3">
                    <li class="visually-hidden" tabindex="-1" data-menu-title="3">
                      {{- childlink.title }} {{ 'layout.navigation.menu' | t -}}
                    </li>
                    <li class="mobile-nav__item border-bottom">
                      <div class="mobile-nav__table">
                        <div class="mobile-nav__table-cell mobile-nav__return">
                          <button type="button" class="btn--link js-toggle-submenu mobile-nav__return-btn" data-target="{{ child_list_handle }}" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="{{ childlink.title }}">
                            {% include 'icon-chevron-left' %}
                          </button>
                        </div>
                        <a href="{{ childlink.url }}"
                          class="mobile-nav__sublist-link mobile-nav__sublist-header"
                          {% if childlink.current %} aria-current="page"{% endif %}
                        >
                          <span class="mobile-nav__label">{{ childlink.title | escape }}</span>
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                    {% for grandchildlink in childlink.links %}
                      <li class="mobile-nav__item{% unless forloop.last %} border-bottom{% endunless %}">
                        <a href="{{ grandchildlink.url }}"
                          class="mobile-nav__sublist-link"
                          {% if grandchildlink.current %} aria-current="page"{% endif %}
                        >
                          <span class="mobile-nav__label">{{ grandchildlink.title | escape }}</span>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </ul>
                {% else %}
                  <a href="{{ childlink.url }}"
                    class="mobile-nav__sublist-link"
                    {% if childlink.current %} aria-current="page"{% endif %}
                  >
                    <span class="mobile-nav__label">{{ childlink.title | escape }}</span>
                  </a>
                {% endif %}
              </li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        {% else %}
          <a href="{{ link.url }}"
            class="mobile-nav__link{% if link.active %} mobile-nav__link--active{% endif %}"
            {% if link.current %} aria-current="page"{% endif %}
          >
            <span class="mobile-nav__label">{{ link.title | escape }}</span>
          </a>
        {% endif %}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</nav>
```

and underneath this is this section which states if the logo is centered do this

```
{% if section.settings.align_logo == 'center' %}
<nav class="small--hide border-bottom" id="AccessibleNav" role="navigation">
{% include 'site-nav', linklist: section.settings.main_linklist, wrapper_class: 'site-nav--centered' %}
 </nav>
 {% endif %}
 </div>
```

but i'm not sure what css to add.
Can anyone please help me achieve this?

Many Thanks
Luke

Comment: You can customize theme easily from html. You can put that nav secction inside the header that'll make it easier. https://i.imgur.com/Fpysuf3.png

Comment: thanks for your response @SaikatRoy, i've checked the header.liquid file and have added the code to my original post, there is some code which states if the logo is aligned left do this, or if it's centre do that, but i don't know what i need to change

Comment: i've moved the if logo = centered section inside the header tags

Comment: you should put nav after the <header> opening tag before all that condition. and clearly you logo is in the center after putting nav section there, some css will be needed to align those section.

Comment: ok have done that, now it's positioned above the logo, but it's taking up the full width of the header container

Comment: took a look . You need to modify some classes. see this- https://i.imgur.com/qLTe72B.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241661/discussion-between-saikat-roy-and-bblj84).